# Clever way of showing the map sending to prime power is outer automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I was asked to find an outer automorphism of a finite group and came up with $x\mapsto x^3$ for $Z_4$ (cyclic group order 4). I went through a lengthy check of all properties to prove that this was indeed an outer automorphism when it occurred to me there probably exists a slicker way to show this. Is there?

Comment: Which part are you trying to shorten, the "outer," or the "automorphism?" Also, can you tell us what you've done so that we might know what would be considered "slicker?"

Answer (score 5):

The only inner automorphism of an abelian group is the identity map!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be a generator of a cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n$. An automorphism  $\alpha$ (one can drop the adjective outer for abelian groups as made clear in the comments) of $C_n$ is entirely known if its image $\alpha(a)$ is known. Indeed, the image of an arbitrary element $a^i \in C_n$ is then $\alpha(a)^i$. So an automorphism of $C_n$  is uniquely determined by a number $d$, namely by the condition $\alpha(a) = a^d$. The inverse is not true. Let $\gcd(d,n) = k > 1$. Let $k'$ be such that $kk'=n$. The element $a^{k'}$ is not $1$ since $k' < n$, but $\alpha(a^{k'}) = 1$ since $dk'$ is a multiple of $n$. The only automorphisms are defined by those $d$ such that $\gcd(n,d) = 1$.